# Cron job command for deleting subfolders of a folder once every 8 hours

Tags: linux, cron, jobs

I am trying to find out the precise command to set up for automatic deletion of the subfolders of a specific folder in Linux. The job should be executed once every 8 hours.

What I came up with so far:

```
find . -type d -path "./home/*****/public_html/data/*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I tried running it once every minute, but it doesn't seem to do anything.
All the subfolders of the `data` folder should be erased.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python to achieve this.

create new python file:

```
vim delete_subfolders.py
```

Put command:

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

sub_folders_pathname = '/home/*****/public_html/data/*'
sub_folders_list = glob.glob(sub_folders_pathname)

for sub_folder_or_file in sub_folders_list:
    #skip deletion if this is a file
    if os.path.isfile(sub_folder_or_file):
        print("found a file name {}, skip deletion".format(sub_folder_or_file))
    #delete the folder
    else:
        shutil.rmtree(sub_folder_or_file)

print("all subfolders have been deleted!!!")
```

save & exit file

run

```
python delete_subfolders.py
```

Put the python in cron job

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
find /home/*****/public_html/data -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

This should do the trick.